# How to deal with a Chrome 18 small-canvas limit?

Tags: html5-canvas

All of my previously-working canvas programs give the black screen of death on Chrome 18. I have seen discussions of complex code giving that but I get it even with:

```
<html><head><title>disaster</title></head><body>
<canvas id="canvas" height="257" width="257"></canvas>
<script type="application/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillText("X",100,100);
</script></body></html>
```

Opera handles this fine but Chrome 18 does so for me only if the canvas is 256x256 or less. If caused by hardware acceleration (HP Support Assistant says my dv6 drivers in Win 7 Pro 64-bit are up-to-date) should I turn it off and how?

Comment: Your code works fine in my Chrome 18. As well as changing it to 250x250.

Comment: **chrome://flags** to enable/disable advanced features

Comment: Back in April when v18 launched, the Samsung Olympic Genome project I was working on was about to launch 4 days after. with the release of chrome 18, it rendered the samsung app unusable for people using 18

I had chatted with Paul Irish and the developer who implemented the 2d-accelerated-canvas feature in hopes that they would release a patch to fix the bug. The issue has to do with the complexity of drawing paths and arcs as they are a part of the Whatwg spec that arent entirely complete yet therefore not fully working within the browser. Luckily I found a fix for samsung app the next day

Comment: oh and fyi, the fillText method is still not too great, it's quite slow, and it also involves the drawing of complex paths, possibly causing the issue in your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and re-installing 18, before my post, had not solved the problem. Richard's post meant my Chrome was corrupted, almost certainly by a loader plug-in that had sneaked into my Chrome and that I had uninstalled. Now uninstalling Chrome's associated data along with it and re-installing solved the problem.